# How to avoid all internet traffic going through VPN connection when established

Tags: network-manager, vpn, tunnel

I am trying to resolve the following problem: I need to be connected to my company's Mikrotik router to reach company's NAS server. It works well. But if I stay connected all the time then all my internet traffic goes through VPN connection and consequentially it is painfully slow.
So how can I force my internet traffic to avoid VPN connection? I believe that it can be solved through VPN settings in Network Manager (GUI) but ticking off "only use for local resources" at Routes in IPv4 just doesn't work - in such case VPN connection is established, internet avoids VPN but it fails to reach NAS server.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your company's Internet Access Policy - you may be about to violate it by subverting the purpose of VPNs. Don't get fired over this. Don't do it.

Comment: @waltinator, It's OK, I checked it. It is no violation. Company encourages this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a route to you NAS server that goes along the VPN. Having the default-route on the VPN is apparently a way to achieve that (depends on details of your networking configuration and environment).

Yes, "only use for local resources" configures the presence of the detault-route.

Often you get automatically specific routes to reach the resources on the VPN. If that doesn't happen, it could be a misconfiguration in the VPN server, on your side or a bug.

Regardless whether that works automatically, you can also add manual, static routes. Find out the IP address you want to reach (`ping NAS-SERVER`, or ask your admin). Possibly, you don't only add a route to that one IP address, but an entire subnet (like 10.0.0.0/8). You can configure that in your NetworkManager GUI. Afterwards re-activate your VPN connection.

Check the assignes routes with `ip route`.

You might also try `traceroute -n NAS-SERVER` to see the way that your IP packets take.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately you told this way-over my ability to comprehend.  This is what I get:peter@BareBone:~$ ip route
default dev ppp0  proto static  scope link  metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
85.10.37.25 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.101  metric 100 
192.168.10.235 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.239  metric 50 Unfortunately I have no Idea which value to use and where to put it.